Flask - Object Changes Only Inside Request Context
I have a strange problem in a large, multi-threaded Flask application that I've managed to reproduce here in about a dozen lines. It appears that whenever I modify the properties of an object inside a function tied to a route in Flask, the property is only modified within the context of that routed function, and outside any routed functions it retains its prior value. As an example, here I define an "app" package in the /app/ directory with __init__.py and routes.py functions.
app/__init__.py:
from flask import Flask

class NumberStore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 1

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.number = number

app = Flask(__name__)
numberstore = NumberStore()

from app import routes

app/routes.py:
from app import app, numberstore

@app.route('/get')
def get():
    return f"The number holder has id {id(numberstore)} and the number is {numberstore.number}"

@app.route('/set')
def set():
    numberstore.set_number(2)
    return f"The number holder has id {id(numberstore)} and the number has been set to {numberstore.number}"

Additionally, I have a convenience script that runs the server in a thread:
runserv.py:
import requests
from multiprocessing import Process

from app import app, numberstore

s = Process(target=lambda : app.run())
s.start()

When I start the server in an interactive session and hit the "/set" endpoint, I expect the value of numberstore.number to change to 2, and it does - for the "/get" and "/set" endpoints. When I access the object outside the context of a routed function, however, the value of numberstore.number remains 1. Likewise, if I manually call the set_number method in the interactive session, the change doesn't propagate to the routed functions. This all happens despite the fact that the object ID remains the same in all cases. As the ID refers to the actual location in memory of the object, this seems impossible to me.
laptop:~/testserver$ python3 -i runserv.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
>>> WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit

>>> numberstore.number
1
>>> id(numberstore)
139855264957008
>>> print(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get").text)
The number holder has id 139855264957008 and the number is 1
>>> print(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/set").text)
The number holder has id 139855264957008 and the number has been set to 2
>>> numberstore.number
1
>>> print(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get").text)
The number holder has id 139855264957008 and the number is 2
>>> numberstore.set_number(3)
>>> numberstore.number
3
>>> print(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get").text)
The number holder has id 139855264957008 and the number is 2

It seems clear to me that this is a feature, not a bug, and I assume it's related to the request sessions that Flask spins up for each request. My question is - why does Flask do this, and is it possible to circumvent it? Almost all the actions taken in my real server are constituted of database changes, which obviously don't have this problem. However, there's one instance in which I really need to modify the properties of a module-level object from within a routed Flask endpoint function. Can this be done?

Figured it out - Flask forks another process for routing endpoints and I didn't catch it. I didn't realize that the object ID would remain the same even inside two separate address spaces.
 python3 -i runserv.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
>>> WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit

>>> print(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get").text)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2024 17:18:57] "GET /get HTTP/1.1" 200 -
The number holder has id 139782623142480, the process id is 69246, and the number is 1
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
69244


